# Item blinking after notifyItemRemoved() called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have a problem with recyclerView animations which uses `DefaultItemAnimator`. I'm calling `notifyItemRemoved(position)` for my last item(LoadingViewHolder). But for some unknown reason after the item was removed the previous item(which was before LoadingViewHolder) blinks.

I tried everything:

- my recycler's height in a layout is match_parent;
- I have `setStableIds` for my adapter and have overridden `getItemId()` properly;
- I also tried to use `setHasFixedSize(true)`;
- I have already tried `notifyItemRangeRemoved` with 1 count;
- I have tried to use `notifyItemChanged` instead of removed;

It is not blinking only when animations turned off but I need those animations.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is there _any_ chance that you are somehow triggering `notifyItemChanged()` on the previous position?

Comment: @BenP. I was thinking about it too. I'll check my code and give the answer

Comment: @BenP. Nope. I have debugged all notify methods and only notifyItemRemoved method is calling

Comment: @BenP. Thanks for the help! I found my problem, it was simple, I have passed the wrong index into notifyItemRemoved

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple:

Check your position which you are passing to notify methods and keep calm